# Possibility to add a popup to when you try to create a question with a particular tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-warning-request

We have some tags that really, are a foundation for bad, closed questions. (looking at you [game-identification]...)

I wonder, would there be a way to popup a notice when you create a question with a 'dangerous' tag? Something that would relay the current tag description, that describes what is a pass or not in that tag?

> USE WITH CAUTION: Only ask if you have a screenshot, video, or audio clip from the game you want to identify. This tag is only for identifying games in movies, pictures, videos, advertisements or otherwise where an unknown game appears - not from a description of what you can recall from memory, or from a picture you drew yourself.

That might help curb down the bad questions issue I guess... but I could also believe that most new users that throw a question in that category will just click next without reading it.

PS: Spitballing here: Could a solution to that problem be to have 'protected tags' where you need a minimum reputation to ask in?

Comment: Protected tags: no, but Tag warning, yes. Also note, this won't stop the people that tag with something else, like [ps4] or something.

Answer (score 14):

> I wonder, would there be a way to popup a notice when you create a question with a 'dangerous' tag? Something that would relay the current tag description, that describes what is a pass or not in that tag?

Yes, this functionality exists in the form of [tag warnings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338875/295232). That link gives an example of how they look like:

[image]

and the answer indicates the process for requesting such a warning:

> If you feel that your community can benefit from having some warnings, [please start a discussion on your meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298890/274323). When the community comes to a consensus on the mechanics of a warning and a text to show, please add the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag and we will pass the request to our developers to set the regex on the site for you.

It seems you've more or less already started step 1...

Comment: I concur. Having a warning like that on the [tag:game-identification] tag might help lower the amount of questions we get.

Comment: There's now a discussion about adding a tag warning for that tag specifically: [Should we add a tag warning to \[game-identification\]?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16574/56295)